# Trying to compare the numbers in 2 arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to create one array with user entered numbers and then another array with random numbers between 0 and 9. I then want to compare the 2 arrays and when they match, echo out a result.

At the moment I'm receiving a fatal error:

`Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`

I know the elements are entered in the array correctly after using `var_dump`.

```
$i = 0;
while(!in_array($lotArray, $userArray)) {
   $i ++;
}

echo "YOU WON it took".$i."times";
?>
```

Comment: If `in_array()` returns `false` once, what makes you think that adding `1` to `$i` will change the result? `in_array` is still false. Consider this: "*Go to the store and buy dinner. 'Okay, I bought some ice cream'. 'No, go to the store and buy dinner'. 'Okay, I bought another ice cream'. 'Go to the store..'*"

Comment: which parameter of in_array() is the value you want to search for? it seems both of them are array.

Comment: if you can write down var_dump output examples for both arrays it would be easier for us to give an help

Comment: Ok I realised that was wrong. After everytime its false I want the array of random numbers to be reconstructed again and then checked with my user entered array.

Comment: Say if i have 1,1,1,1,1 in my first array, i only want it to work if the array with random numbers has 1,1,1,1,1 in as well

Comment: True, I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an iterative approach to compare each number is `Oh(n²)` because you have to compare X times X numbers.

Instead, take a simple approach:

- Sort both arrays in the same way. (`Oh(n log n)` each)
- create a string out of them (`Oh(n)`)
- compare the strings. (`Oh(n)`)

like

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3);
$arr2 = array(2,3,1);

asort($arr1);
asort($arr2);

$string1 = implode($arr1, "_"); // "1_2_3"
$string2 = implode($arr2, "_"); // "1_2_3"

if ($string1 == $string2){
  echo "You've won!";
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**this works fine**

```
$count     =   //your wish of getting random numbers.
$randarr   =   range('0','9');

$randarr   =   array_rand($randarr,$count);

$difference=   array_diff($randarr,$arr);   //let $arr be your array

if(count($difference)==0)
{
    //your display code
}
```

this enables you to create as many random numbers as the user selects.

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to compare two arrays (all numbers must be the same, in the same order) :

```
$a1 = array(1, 9, 4);
$a2 = array(1, 9, 4);

if (count(array_diff($a1,$a2)) == 0)
    echo "Both array match";
```